# ERROR -- : undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rally

I am getting the above error when I try to run /update_project_permissions.rb script of Rally-User-Management.

update_project_permissions.rb

```
#include for rally json library gem
require 'rally_api'
require 'csv'
require './lib/multi_io.rb'
require './lib/rally_user_helper.rb'
require './lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb'

$project_identifier_arg = ARGV[0]
$new_permission_arg = ARGV[1]

if $project_identifier_arg.nil? || $new_permission_arg.nil? then
puts "Usage: ruby update_all_project_permissions.rb \"My Project\" \"Editor\""
puts "or: ruby update_all_project_permissions 12345678910 \"No Access\""
puts "Where in number form, the project identifier is the Project's ObjectID."
end

begin
go_update_project_permissions($project_identifier_arg, $new_permission_arg)
end
```

which calls file 
lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb at

[go_update_project_permissions](https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-User-Management/blob/master/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb)
[go_update_project_permissions](https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-User-Management/blob/master/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb)

The command line argument is -  ruby update_project_permissions.rb "40880544785" "No Access"

I am getting the following error

ERROR -- : undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:92:in `is_workspace_admin'

c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:137:in `update_project_permissions'

c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:309:in `block in go_update_project_permissions'

c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:308:in `each'

c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:308:in `go_update_project_permissions'
update_project_permissions.rb:38:in

[2015-08-10T15:38:28.854098 #15504] ERROR -- : 
["c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:92:in `is_workspace_admin'", "
c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:137:in `update_project_permissions'", "
c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:309:in `block in go_update_project_permissions'", "
c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:308:in `each'", "
c:/Users/vorad/Documents/Rally-User-Management/lib/go_update_project_permissions.rb:308:in `go_update_project_permissions'", "update_project_permissions.rb:38:in "]E,

[2015-08-10T15:38:28.857098 #15504] ERROR -- : undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Does the script successfully process any updates before running into the error? or does it error out immediately?

Comment: @user4211235 before running into error it successfully creates connection, caches work-spaces, project, users and then ask for permission to update to "No Access" for all non-(sub, works pace, project) admins and then it immediately encounters error.

Comment: This is a bug when user permissions collection for a given user contains no user - thanks for finding this. Fix posted below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for finding this bug. There's an updated version here:

https://github.com/markwilliams970/Rally-User-Management

That should address the problem.

Comment: is there a similar bug in for user_permissions_syncer.rb cause I am getting the same error there too. Please help  me solve it.

Comment: Sorry about that - re-clone this repo:

https://github.com/markwilliams970/Rally-User-Management

which contains a fix for the issue in the syncer.